# Mapping a custom relationship in Entity Framework 4 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a model Vehicle and another Model so there's a One-to-Many relationship from vehicle to model.
The vehicle class is defined like this:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I am mapping these classes to an existing database so I am doing this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().ToTable("TB_Vehicles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().Property(x => x.Color).HasColumnName("DR_Color");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().ToTable("TB_Models");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().Property(x => x.ModelId).HasColumnName("CD_Model");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("DS_Description");
```

So my table TB_Models has a column CD_Model which is a primary key and my table TB_Vehicles also has a column CD_Model which is the foreign key. 
How can I map that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map it as follows.

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
            .HasOptional(v => v.Model)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("CD_Model"));
```

If the Foreign key is non nullable use `HasRequired` instead of `HasOptional`.